# How do I display a number sequence where it displays the number as much as its value

Tags: java

I want to make a sequence where I have to input the starting and ending number of the sequence

```
for (int o = startNum; o <= endNum; o++)
        {
            total += o ;
            
            for(int row = startNum; row <= o; row++)
            {
                System.out.print(o + "");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Output :

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

when starting at 1 its fine but when I start at a higher value is where the problem is

Output :

```
3
44
555
6666
77777
```

I want to display the starting number as much as the value Ive input

my desired output is :

```
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
```

Comment: What does your title mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner for loop `for(int row = startNum; row <= o; row++)` does `o - startNum + 1` iterations, when in reality it needs to do `o` iterations. Your code works for the case of `1` because `o - startNum + 1` is equal to `o` when `startNum` is equal to 1.

Changing your code to the following should solve your problem:

```
for (int o = startNum; o <= endNum; o++) {
    for(int row = 1; row <= o; row++) {
        System.out.print(o + "");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you can use the *[String#repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))* method.

```java
String.valueOf(x).repeat(x)
```